# Windows 11: Clicking Icon on Taskbar Does Not Switch to Program

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

After my upgrade to windows 11, clicking on an icon on the taskbar does not display the program on front.
Clicking on the popup above it, bring it on front. That is annoying when there is only one screen open from that program to move over again.

In windows 10 there was a solution for that, but that is not available in windows 11

[Clicking Icon on Taskbar Does Not Switch to Program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/clicking-icon-on-taskbar-does-not-switch-to-program-f9df8a35-ff86-9bd8-c85a-499ac228cf9f)

Does anybody knows a solution for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Apparently, Windows 11 is still a fork in progress: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/11/two-months-in-windows-11-is-still-a-work-in-progress/ .

Comment: There are several things to send feedback about (fat taskbars, no good right context, no toolbars) but for what is there, quality is very  good and all is well here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might be the most annoying issue I was encountering on Windows 11. When Visual Studio 2022 is running the debugger, the Windows taskbar becomes unresponsive and requires you to click multiple times to get the window to show.

The current fix I've found was to disable "Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging" via the Tools -> Options dialog.

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Options Dialog Window]

Comment: Perfect!  That fixed it for me!  Thanks, that was really frustrating.

Comment: Awesome, I wonder how you figured out this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Ateik i got so frustrated with this issue, it completely breaks your workflow when coding, so i just decided to spend an entire day trying to find it :)

Comment: @bose Thanks for spending your time on this. I have been struggling with this for weeks now, and suddenly it got resolved thanks to you. Thanks a lot. Wish I could give more than 1 upvote!

Comment: this worked for me too!

Comment: This was what worked for me. I thought it was a Windows 11 issue, but I have a server app running under debug mode the whole time I am working and was wondering what's going on.

Comment: It worked. I love you

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) seems to be part of the problem for me. I can get this issue whether I'm debugging or not, and regardless of this fix. Also sometimes even when Visual Studio is closed. The problem goes away without fail if I close SSMS.

Answer (score 4):

There're [few reports](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/report-an-issue/windows-11-clicking-taskbar-icon-doesn-t-always-switch-to-that/m-p/3015066/thread-id/5563) that it only occurs with VS 2022 opened, so with me. Temporary workaround is clicking on empty taskbar space, it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This issue is caused by more applications than VS 2022. I am starting to suspect Citrix and possibly Hyper-V.

Comment: Ouch.  I can confirm VS 2022 caused it for me.  Also clicking on an empty part of the taskbar is a valid temp fix.   Right clicking helps sometimes but isn't consistent.  As someone who has a lot of apps running....  this bug hurts...

Comment: The same is for Android Studio (at least, I work with it).

Comment: It's not only "_with VS 2022 opened_". With e.g. two Win Explorer windows open I get two previews of these windows rather than restoring them. And [we still cannot switch taskbar grouping off...](https://www.howtogeek.com/894996/windows-11-will-finally-let-you-turn-off-taskbar-grouping/). And it's even worse with e.g. Firefox: Though there's just one window of it open clicking its taskbar icon shows just previews of all of its browser tabs. :(

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:
When you hover over the open programs on the taskbar, you can right click on the application windows and restore.

And Thanks @Niksr for your workaround

Comment: Unfortunately there is NO _Restore_ in the context menu with the Win 11 (Version 22H2, Build 22621.1992) I use here.

Answer (score 0):

see microsoft answer here

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/window-switching-in-window-11-taskbar-stops-workin/1597282

"This issue is caused by an interaction between the WebView2 component used by Visual Studio and the Windows 11 taskbar. The Windows 11 taskbar team is currently actively investigating.

Update: the Windows 11 taskbar team has a fix, which makes the taskbar resilient to the issue triggered by WebView2, but it is uncertain when that fix will be released. However, the WebView2 team also has a fix so that WebView2 won’t trigger the problem in the first place. We expect that fix to be rolled out in the next stable WebView2 release in early March. We will provide further information here when that fix is available (for most people, their WebView2 installation should update automatically when the new release rolls out)."